# Consider the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,…99,100\}$, maximum number of elements that can be chosen making sure that their sum does not exceed 1000?.

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

**Consider the set $A = \{1,2,3,4,…99,100\}$, i.e. the set of natural numbers less or equal to $100$.
Elements are chosen at random from this set without repetition of elements.**

What is the maximum number of elements that can be chosen making sure that their sum does not exceed $1000$?. Clearly justify your answer.

My solution so far is as follows:

Assuming worst case scenario, largest numbers are chosen first so:

$100 + 99 + 98 + ... + 91 + 90$, etc.

$100 + 99 + 98 + ... + 92 + 91 = (100 + 91) \times 5 = 955$

Adding 90 would make the sum exceed 1000, so the maximum number of elements is 10

However, the answer key says the answer is $11$ elements - is my working out correct or is there simply an error? This is from a Grade 11 maths exam practice.

Comment: No, your answer is correct.

Comment: I don't quite understand, why can't we choose $1,2,3,4,\ldots,11,12,13,\ldots$ and so on? For example $1+2+\ldots+15=120$ which is 15 elements

Comment: elements are chosen at random

Comment: Ah, ok, this makes sense then.

Comment: Even if the list includes zero, the answer will be 10. Mainly, because if you have to choose randomly, you must consider the "worst" scenario.

Comment: Listing $11$ elements with a sum greater than $1000$, as you have done, is a good demonstration that the answer is at most $10$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. In the worst case scenario, the sum of $11$ numbers will exceed $1000$. So, to be certain that the sum does not exceed $1000$, the maximum number of elements that can be chosen is $10$.